# Getting Unspecified error in QTP

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, automation, automated-tests, qtp

I'm trying to execute the below script in QTP which opens F12 developer option on a webpage and checks the network data for 404 error by verifying the Network data weblist. But I get an "*Unspecified error*" while executing the line

```
If trim(Browser("creationtime:=0").WinListView("regexpwndtitle:=Summary View ListView Control").GetSubItem(rcount,4))="404" then
```

Can you please advise Why I get this error.

```
Code:
Browser("creationtime:=0").highlight

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "{F12}"
wait 20
Browser("creationtime:=0").WinListView("regexpwndtitle:=Summary View ListView Control").Click
wait 2
WshShell.SendKeys "{F5}"

Browser("creationtime:=0").Refresh
wait 20


 totalcount= Browser("creationtime:=0").WinListView("regexpwndtitle:=Summary View ListView Control").GetItemsCount


 For rcount = 1 to totalcount-1
     If trim(Browser("creationtime:=0").WinListView("regexpwndtitle:=Summary View ListView Control").GetSubItem(rcount,4))="404" then
        flag=true
        Exit for
     End if

 next

If flag Then
    msgbox "404 is present in row "&rcount
    else
    msgbox "404 is not present"
End If
```

Comment: Its working fine for me in IE11, by any chance you running this from QC or ALM or something ?

Comment: No, But in this code instead of the creationtime I give the webpage name where it needs to test. This script is running fine on a normal page for me too. But the issue seems to happen in the application that I'm working on.

Comment: Can we see that line please?